# jQuery Simplebar plugin doesn't work with class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplebar

Using [Simplebar Plugin](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) I try to create scrollbar with class element like [this documents](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar#other-usages). but in action this plugin doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="simple-bar">
  //data
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.simple-bar').each(element, new SimpleBar());
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/amtfu9Lh/)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/  I'm not sure why those docs show the `each(element, new SimpleBar())` as a valid pattern.  There, at least in the api, is no definition for each having two arguments.

Comment: @Taplar: `$('.simple-bar').each(element => new SimpleBar(element))` doesn't work.

Comment: crap, because of the stupid index.  `$('.simple-bar').each((index, element) => new SimpleBar(element));`

Comment: Also related to my "it's not in the api", https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L71  <= the source code for `jQuery.fn.each` also shows it only takes in one argument.  `jQuery.each` does take two, but that's not the form used in the docs.  So as far as I can tell, that's a bug in their (SimpleBars) documentation.

Comment: `$('.simple-bar').each((index, element) => new SimpleBar(element));` your code work now. please add to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.myElements').each(element, new SimpleBar());
```

This is the example in the SimpleBar documentation that your question is relating two.  This example in the documentation is flawed.

There are two forms of `each()` in jQuery.  There is the `jQuery.each` method and the `jQuery.fn.each` method, which is a wrapper around the first one.  The difference being that `jQuery.fn` methods are designed to act upon an instance of jQuery with a result stack in it (ex. the result of a `$(...)` expression).  The `jQuery.each` is not written to operate upon an existing instance, and is instead expected to be given both the elements to operate upon, and the callback related to the work needing to be done.

Given this, the usage that their documentation shows is incorrectly trying to use the `jQuery.fn.each` as if it were the `jQuery.each` form.

```
$('.simple-bar').each((index, element) => new SimpleBar(element));`
```

This form correctly uses the `jQuery.fn.each` version, giving it just the callback that will be used to perform work against the result stack in the jQuery instance.